# How to generate list of weekday dates excluding holidays as per defined rule

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have master dates table workingDates that have 3 columns

> a. wd:(type int ) This column has all working dates in int format for
>   a year weekends and holidays are not included.
>
> b. fulldate (datatype date): same as wd but in date format.
>
> c. dayname : this contains weekdayname like monday,tuesday.

I want to generate a list of two dates(two columns ) for each month as per the following rule.

a. second Friday of each month (if second Friday is a holiday for that month then that date would not be there in workingDates.wd, in this case, I need previous working i.e: Thursday or Wednesday whatever working day available in the table )

b. Monday after third Friday for each month ( in this case if Monday is a holiday I need next working day i.e Tuesday or Wednesday whatever is working day available in the table )

I need your help to create the query in this scenario.

output expected :

```
year month rule_1_dates rule_2_dates

2019  Jan     20190111    20190121
```

and so on…….

base table workingDates data :

```
    declare @workingDates table (wd int , fulldate date , [dayname] varchar(30))

    insert into @workingDates values (20190102,’2019-01-02′,’Wednesday’)
    insert into @workingDates values (20190103,’2019-01-03′,’Thursday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190104,’2019-01-04′,’Friday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190107,’2019-01-07′,’Monday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190108,’2019-01-08′,’Tuesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190109,’2019-01-09′,’Wednesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190110,’2019-01-10′,’Thursday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190111,’2019-01-11′,’Friday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190114,’2019-01-14′,’Monday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190115,’2019-01-15′,’Tuesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190116,’2019-01-16′,’Wednesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190117,’2019-01-17′,’Thursday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190118,’2019-01-18′,’Friday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190121,’2019-01-21′,’Monday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190122,’2019-01-22′,’Tuesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190123,’2019-01-23′,’Wednesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190124,’2019-01-24′,’Thursday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190125,’2019-01-25′,’Friday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190128,’2019-01-28′,’Monday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190129,’2019-01-29′,’Tuesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190130,’2019-01-30′,’Wednesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190131,’2019-01-31′,’Thursday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190201,’2019-02-01′,’Friday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190204,’2019-02-04′,’Monday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190205,’2019-02-05′,’Tuesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190206,’2019-02-06′,’Wednesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190207,’2019-02-07′,’Thursday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190208,’2019-02-08′,’Friday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190211,’2019-02-11′,’Monday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190212,’2019-02-12′,’Tuesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190213,’2019-02-13′,’Wednesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190214,’2019-02-14′,’Thursday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190215,’2019-02-15′,’Friday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190218,’2019-02-18′,’Monday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190219,’2019-02-19′,’Tuesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190220,’2019-02-20′,’Wednesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190221,’2019-02-21′,’Thursday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190222,’2019-02-22′,’Friday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190225,’2019-02-25′,’Monday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190226,’2019-02-26′,’Tuesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190227,’2019-02-27′,’Wednesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190228,’2019-02-28′,’Thursday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190301,’2019-03-01′,’Friday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190304,’2019-03-04′,’Monday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190305,’2019-03-05′,’Tuesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190306,’2019-03-06′,’Wednesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190307,’2019-03-07′,’Thursday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190308,’2019-03-08′,’Friday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190311,’2019-03-11′,’Monday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190312,’2019-03-12′,’Tuesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190313,’2019-03-13′,’Wednesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190314,’2019-03-14′,’Thursday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190315,’2019-03-15′,’Friday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190318,’2019-03-18′,’Monday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190319,’2019-03-19′,’Tuesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190320,’2019-03-20′,’Wednesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190321,’2019-03-21′,’Thursday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190322,’2019-03-22′,’Friday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190325,’2019-03-25′,’Monday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190326,’2019-03-26′,’Tuesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190327,’2019-03-27′,’Wednesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190328,’2019-03-28′,’Thursday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190329,’2019-03-29′,’Friday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190401,’2019-04-01′,’Monday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190402,’2019-04-02′,’Tuesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190403,’2019-04-03′,’Wednesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190404,’2019-04-04′,’Thursday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190405,’2019-04-05′,’Friday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190408,’2019-04-08′,’Monday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190409,’2019-04-09′,’Tuesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190410,’2019-04-10′,’Wednesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190411,’2019-04-11′,’Thursday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190412,’2019-04-12′,’Friday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190415,’2019-04-15′,’Monday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190416,’2019-04-16′,’Tuesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190417,’2019-04-17′,’Wednesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190418,’2019-04-18′,’Thursday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190423,’2019-04-23′,’Tuesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190424,’2019-04-24′,’Wednesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190425,’2019-04-25′,’Thursday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190426,’2019-04-26′,’Friday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190429,’2019-04-29′,’Monday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190430,’2019-04-30′,’Tuesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190501,’2019-05-01′,’Wednesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190502,’2019-05-02′,’Thursday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190503,’2019-05-03′,’Friday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190506,’2019-05-06′,’Monday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190507,’2019-05-07′,’Tuesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190508,’2019-05-08′,’Wednesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190509,’2019-05-09′,’Thursday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190510,’2019-05-10′,’Friday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190513,’2019-05-13′,’Monday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190514,’2019-05-14′,’Tuesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190515,’2019-05-15′,’Wednesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190516,’2019-05-16′,’Thursday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190517,’2019-05-17′,’Friday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190520,’2019-05-20′,’Monday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190521,’2019-05-21′,’Tuesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190522,’2019-05-22′,’Wednesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190523,’2019-05-23′,’Thursday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190524,’2019-05-24′,’Friday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190527,’2019-05-27′,’Monday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190528,’2019-05-28′,’Tuesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190529,’2019-05-29′,’Wednesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190530,’2019-05-30′,’Thursday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190531,’2019-05-31′,’Friday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190603,’2019-06-03′,’Monday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190604,’2019-06-04′,’Tuesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190605,’2019-06-05′,’Wednesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190606,’2019-06-06′,’Thursday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190607,’2019-06-07′,’Friday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190610,’2019-06-10′,’Monday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190611,’2019-06-11′,’Tuesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190612,’2019-06-12′,’Wednesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190613,’2019-06-13′,’Thursday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190614,’2019-06-14′,’Friday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190617,’2019-06-17′,’Monday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190618,’2019-06-18′,’Tuesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190619,’2019-06-19′,’Wednesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190620,’2019-06-20′,’Thursday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190621,’2019-06-21′,’Friday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190624,’2019-06-24′,’Monday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190625,’2019-06-25′,’Tuesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190626,’2019-06-26′,’Wednesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190627,’2019-06-27′,’Thursday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190628,’2019-06-28′,’Friday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190701,’2019-07-01′,’Monday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190702,’2019-07-02′,’Tuesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190703,’2019-07-03′,’Wednesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190704,’2019-07-04′,’Thursday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190705,’2019-07-05′,’Friday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190708,’2019-07-08′,’Monday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190709,’2019-07-09′,’Tuesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190710,’2019-07-10′,’Wednesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190711,’2019-07-11′,’Thursday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190712,’2019-07-12′,’Friday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190715,’2019-07-15′,’Monday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190716,’2019-07-16′,’Tuesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190717,’2019-07-17′,’Wednesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190718,’2019-07-18′,’Thursday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190719,’2019-07-19′,’Friday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190722,’2019-07-22′,’Monday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190723,’2019-07-23′,’Tuesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190724,’2019-07-24′,’Wednesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190725,’2019-07-25′,’Thursday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190726,’2019-07-26′,’Friday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190729,’2019-07-29′,’Monday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190730,’2019-07-30′,’Tuesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190731,’2019-07-31′,’Wednesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190801,’2019-08-01′,’Thursday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190802,’2019-08-02′,’Friday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190805,’2019-08-05′,’Monday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190806,’2019-08-06′,’Tuesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190807,’2019-08-07′,’Wednesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190808,’2019-08-08′,’Thursday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190809,’2019-08-09′,’Friday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190812,’2019-08-12′,’Monday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190813,’2019-08-13′,’Tuesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190814,’2019-08-14′,’Wednesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190815,’2019-08-15′,’Thursday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190816,’2019-08-16′,’Friday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190819,’2019-08-19′,’Monday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190820,’2019-08-20′,’Tuesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190821,’2019-08-21′,’Wednesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190822,’2019-08-22′,’Thursday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190823,’2019-08-23′,’Friday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190826,’2019-08-26′,’Monday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190827,’2019-08-27′,’Tuesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190828,’2019-08-28′,’Wednesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190829,’2019-08-29′,’Thursday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190830,’2019-08-30′,’Friday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190902,’2019-09-02′,’Monday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190903,’2019-09-03′,’Tuesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190904,’2019-09-04′,’Wednesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190905,’2019-09-05′,’Thursday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190906,’2019-09-06′,’Friday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190909,’2019-09-09′,’Monday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190910,’2019-09-10′,’Tuesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190911,’2019-09-11′,’Wednesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190912,’2019-09-12′,’Thursday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190913,’2019-09-13′,’Friday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190916,’2019-09-16′,’Monday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190917,’2019-09-17′,’Tuesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190918,’2019-09-18′,’Wednesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190919,’2019-09-19′,’Thursday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190920,’2019-09-20′,’Friday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190923,’2019-09-23′,’Monday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190924,’2019-09-24′,’Tuesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190925,’2019-09-25′,’Wednesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190926,’2019-09-26′,’Thursday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190927,’2019-09-27′,’Friday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20190930,’2019-09-30′,’Monday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191001,’2019-10-01′,’Tuesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191002,’2019-10-02′,’Wednesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191003,’2019-10-03′,’Thursday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191004,’2019-10-04′,’Friday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191007,’2019-10-07′,’Monday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191008,’2019-10-08′,’Tuesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191009,’2019-10-09′,’Wednesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191010,’2019-10-10′,’Thursday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191011,’2019-10-11′,’Friday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191014,’2019-10-14′,’Monday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191015,’2019-10-15′,’Tuesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191016,’2019-10-16′,’Wednesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191017,’2019-10-17′,’Thursday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191018,’2019-10-18′,’Friday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191021,’2019-10-21′,’Monday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191022,’2019-10-22′,’Tuesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191023,’2019-10-23′,’Wednesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191024,’2019-10-24′,’Thursday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191025,’2019-10-25′,’Friday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191028,’2019-10-28′,’Monday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191029,’2019-10-29′,’Tuesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191030,’2019-10-30′,’Wednesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191031,’2019-10-31′,’Thursday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191101,’2019-11-01′,’Friday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191104,’2019-11-04′,’Monday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191105,’2019-11-05′,’Tuesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191106,’2019-11-06′,’Wednesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191107,’2019-11-07′,’Thursday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191108,’2019-11-08′,’Friday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191111,’2019-11-11′,’Monday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191112,’2019-11-12′,’Tuesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191113,’2019-11-13′,’Wednesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191114,’2019-11-14′,’Thursday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191115,’2019-11-15′,’Friday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191118,’2019-11-18′,’Monday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191119,’2019-11-19′,’Tuesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191120,’2019-11-20′,’Wednesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191121,’2019-11-21′,’Thursday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191122,’2019-11-22′,’Friday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191125,’2019-11-25′,’Monday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191126,’2019-11-26′,’Tuesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191127,’2019-11-27′,’Wednesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191128,’2019-11-28′,’Thursday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191129,’2019-11-29′,’Friday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191202,’2019-12-02′,’Monday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191203,’2019-12-03′,’Tuesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191204,’2019-12-04′,’Wednesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191205,’2019-12-05′,’Thursday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191206,’2019-12-06′,’Friday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191209,’2019-12-09′,’Monday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191210,’2019-12-10′,’Tuesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191211,’2019-12-11′,’Wednesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191216,’2019-12-16′,’Monday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191217,’2019-12-17′,’Tuesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191218,’2019-12-18′,’Wednesday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191219,’2019-12-19′,’Thursday’)

    insert into @workingDates values (20191220,’2019-12-20′,’Friday’)
    insert into @workingDates values (20191224,’2019-12-24′,’Tuesday’)
    insert into @workingDates values (20191227,’2019-12-27′,’Friday’)
    insert into @workingDates values (20191230,’2019-12-30′,’Monday’)
    insert into @workingDates values (20191231,’2019-12-31′,’Tuesday’)
```

Comment: Your calendar table should hold ALL dates, not just some dates. Since you don't have that you will need to first generate the list of all dates, then left join to your workingDates table so you can do things like find the third Thursday.

Comment: @SeanLange can I assign week number and identify working weekday? Can you suggest better approach?.

Comment: No need to insert date by date into the calendar Table: you can generate it using Recursivity, look at my Script below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the complete code

1) I filled the holiday dates with those of **Tunisia** => Table ***@tabholiday***

Feel free to fill it with your country holiday dates

2) I generated a dynmaic table with all dates of a given year (here 2019) => Table ***@calendar***

3) The days (second Friday for each month of before if friday is a holiday) are stored in table @tab_friday

4) The days (Monday after third Friday of after if Monday is a holiday) are stored in table @tab_monday

5) Then the Final result is the jointure of these two tables.

using SQL RECURSIVITY with CTE and Union All

```
declare @tabholiday as table(holiday_date date)
declare @tab_friday as table (m int,date_found date)
declare @tab_monday as table (m int,date_found date)
insert into @tabholiday values('2019/01/07'),('2019/01/11'),('2019/03/20'),('2019/04/09'),('2019/05/01'),('2019/07/25'),('2019/08/13'),('2019/10/15')
declare @calendar as table(wd int,fulldate date,dayname varchar(20),m int,weekday_rank_month int,holiday int)

--Script by Kemal AL GAZZAH
--19/04/2019

set dateformat dmy

--Filling the @Calendar Table------------

;WITH cte as (SELECT cast('01/01/2019' as date) as d 
UNION ALL SELECT dateadd(day,1,d)  AS d FROM cte WHERE year(dateadd(day,1,d))=2019 ) 
insert into @calendar SELECT cast(replace(d,'-','') as int) wd,d fulldate,
case datepart(w,d)
when 1 then 'Sunday'
when 2 then 'Monday'
when 3 then 'Tuesday'
when 4 then 'Wednesday'
when 5 then 'Thursday'
when 6 then 'Friday'
when 7 then 'Satuday'
end

 [dayname] ,month(d) [M]
 ,row_number() over (partition by datepart(w,d),month(d) order by d) weekday_rank_month,case isnull(t2.holiday_date,'') when '' then 0 else 1 end [holiday]

 FROM cte t1 left outer join @tabholiday t2 on t1.d=t2.holiday_date

  order by d 
 OPTION (MAXRECURSION 366);

 --1)-Filling Friday Table

 with cte as(
 select t1.m [Month],t1.fulldate[secondfriday],t1.holiday,t2.fulldate[secondfriday1] from @calendar t1 
 outer apply(select top 1 * from @calendar t2 where t2.fulldate < t1.fulldate and t2.holiday=0 order by fulldate desc) t2
 /*left outer join @calendar t2 on t1.weekday_rank_month=2 and t1.dayname='friday' and t1.holiday=1 and dateadd(day,-1,t1.fulldate)=t2.fulldate and t2.holiday=0
 left outer join @calendar t3 on t1.weekday_rank_month=2 and t1.dayname='friday' and t1.holiday=1 and dateadd(day,-2,t1.fulldate)=t3.fulldate and t2.holiday=1*/
  where t1.weekday_rank_month=2 and t1.dayname='friday')
  insert into @tab_friday select month,case
  when holiday =0 then secondfriday
  else secondfriday1  
  end [second friday or before (if that friday is a holiday)] from cte;


  --2)-Filling Monday Table
  ;
  with cte as
  (
  select t1.m[Month],t2.fulldate d1,t2.holiday,t3.fulldate d2  from @calendar t1 
  outer apply(select top 1 * from  @calendar t2 where t2.dayname='monday' and t2.fulldate > t1.fulldate order by fulldate) t2
  outer apply (select top 1 * from @calendar t3 where fulldate > t2.fulldate and holiday=0 and month(fulldate)=t1.m order by fulldate ) t3
  /*left outer join @calendar t3 on t2.holiday=1 and t3.holiday=0 and dateadd(day,1,t1.fulldate)=t3.fulldate
  left outer join @calendar t4 on t2.holiday=1 and t3.holiday=1 and dateadd(day,2,t1.fulldate)=t4.fulldate*/
  where t1.weekday_rank_month=3 and t1.dayname='friday')
  insert into @tab_monday 
  select 
  [Month],
  case 
  when holiday=0 then d1 
  else d2
  end [Monday after third friday(or after f monday is a holiday)] from cte


  --select * from @tab_monday

  --3)-Jointure Betwwen Friday and Monday Table 

 select t1.m [Month],t1.date_found [Second Friday or before],t2.date_found[Monday after third friday or after] from @tab_friday t1 inner join @tab_monday t2 on t1.m=t2.m
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. 

can you please adjust your query to consider more than 2 days to fetch working friday since you have consider only two consecutive holidays but there could be situation where holidays can be anything in case of emergency so we have to adjust days dynamically. 

Please suggest.

Comment: I adjusted the script to fetch the day which is not holiday (for (1) friday and (2) monday) by replacing left outer join by OUTER APPLY

Comment: I also adde a correction to the script, it was missing a condition in the script fetching the monday after the 3rd friday