# valid dates generator per course schedule

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table @course_schedule  where all course name and schedule of classes is listed. 
There 2 parent courses and all other courses are derived from that having some changes in schedule.

Parent courses are very basic course and classes are on daily basis except weekends and holidays.

All the valid class dates for parent are in table @parent_course_dates, there could be some change in holidays pattern 
so both parent courses valid dates are captured.

There is one more table @alldates where dates data is captured with dayname.

I want to create logic that will generate

lecture_dates
lab_dates
doubt_session_date
Any_other_date

As per description column mentioned in table @course_schedule for each date type. Dates will follow parent course schedule 
for all weekday (monday-friday) dates schedule and @all_dates table for any weekend dates (saturday).

If any weekday (mon-friday) is not availble in @parent_course_dates table that means that day would be holiday and should not be 
considered for class in this case next or previous date should be picked up on the basis of description i.e if description is
Monday after third thursday , and monday is holiday then tuesday should be picked if tuesday is again a holiday then 
wednesday should be picked.

In case of definition like wednesday before third thursday, and wednesday is holiday then tuesday should be picked.

In case of saturday there must not be any impact of holiday.

Following is sample data.

```
     declare @course_schedule table (id int, course_name varchar(100), parent_course_id int, course_type char(5),
     lecture_schedule_desc varchar(500), lab_schedule_desc varchar(500),doubts_session_desc varchar(100), 
     active_in_months varchar(100) )

     declare @parent_course_dates table (id int identity, course_id int , valid_date int )

     declare @alldates table (valid_date int,[dayname] varchar(100))

     insert into @course_schedule 
     values(101, 'dax_course', 1, 'c1','Monday after third thursday of month in active_in_months'
     ,'wednesday before third thursday of month in active_in_months' ,'saturday after second friday of month in active_in_months' ,'1,2,3')

     insert into @course_schedule 
     values(111, 'dax2_course', 1, 'c1','Tuesday after second thursday of month in active_in_months'
     ,'monday after third friday of month in active_in_months' ,'Friday after second monday of month in active_in_months' ,'3,4')

     insert into @course_schedule 
     values(201, 'ml_course', 35, 'c1','Monday after third thursday of month in active_in_months'
     ,'wednesday before third thursday of month in active_in_months' ,'saturday after second monday of month in active_in_months' ,'1,2')


    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190102')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190103')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190104')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190107')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190108')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190109')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190110')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190111')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190114')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190115')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190116')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190117')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190118')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190121')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190122')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190123')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190124')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190125')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190128')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190129')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190130')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190131')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190201')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190204')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190205')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190206')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190207')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190208')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190211')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190212')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190213')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190214')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190215')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190218')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190219')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190220')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190221')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190222')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190225')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190226')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190227')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190228')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190301')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190304')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190305')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190306')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190307')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190308')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190311')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190312')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190313')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190314')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190315')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190318')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190319')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190320')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190321')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190322')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190325')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190326')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190327')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190328')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190329')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190401')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190402')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190403')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190404')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190405')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190408')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190409')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190410')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190411')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190412')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190415')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190416')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190417')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190418')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190423')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190424')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190425')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190426')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190429')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20190430')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('1 ','20191231')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190102')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190103')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190104')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190107')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190108')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190109')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190110')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190111')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190114')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190115')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190116')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190117')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190118')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190121')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190122')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190123')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190124')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190125')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190128')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190129')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190130')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190131')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190201')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190204')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190205')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190206')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190207')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190208')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190211')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190212')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190213')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190214')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190215')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190218')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190219')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190220')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190221')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190222')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190225')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190226')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190227')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190228')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190301')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190304')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190305')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190306')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190307')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190308')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190311')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190312')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190313')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190314')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190315')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190318')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190319')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190320')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190321')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190322')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190325')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190326')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190327')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190328')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190329')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190401')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190402')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190403')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190404')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190405')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190408')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190409')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190410')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190411')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190412')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190415')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190416')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190417')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190418')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190422')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190423')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190424')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190425')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190426')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190429')
    insert into @parent_course_dates values('35','20190430')

    insert into @alldates values ('20190101','Tuesday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190102','Wednesday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190103','Thursday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190104','Friday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190105','Saturday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190106','Sunday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190107','Monday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190108','Tuesday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190109','Wednesday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190110','Thursday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190111','Friday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190112','Saturday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190113','Sunday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190114','Monday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190115','Tuesday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190116','Wednesday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190117','Thursday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190118','Friday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190119','Saturday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190120','Sunday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190121','Monday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190122','Tuesday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190123','Wednesday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190124','Thursday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190125','Friday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190126','Saturday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190127','Sunday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190128','Monday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190129','Tuesday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190130','Wednesday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190131','Thursday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190201','Friday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190202','Saturday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190203','Sunday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190204','Monday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190205','Tuesday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190206','Wednesday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190207','Thursday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190208','Friday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190209','Saturday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190210','Sunday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190211','Monday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190212','Tuesday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190213','Wednesday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190214','Thursday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190215','Friday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190216','Saturday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190217','Sunday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190218','Monday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190219','Tuesday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190220','Wednesday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190221','Thursday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190222','Friday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190223','Saturday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190224','Sunday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190225','Monday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190226','Tuesday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190227','Wednesday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190228','Thursday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190301','Friday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190302','Saturday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190303','Sunday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190304','Monday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190305','Tuesday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190306','Wednesday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190307','Thursday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190308','Friday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190309','Saturday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190310','Sunday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190311','Monday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190312','Tuesday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190313','Wednesday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190314','Thursday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190315','Friday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190316','Saturday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190317','Sunday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190318','Monday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190319','Tuesday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190320','Wednesday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190321','Thursday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190322','Friday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190323','Saturday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190324','Sunday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190325','Monday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190326','Tuesday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190327','Wednesday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190328','Thursday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190329','Friday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190330','Saturday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190331','Sunday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190401','Monday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190402','Tuesday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190403','Wednesday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190404','Thursday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190405','Friday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190406','Saturday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190407','Sunday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190408','Monday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190409','Tuesday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190410','Wednesday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190411','Thursday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190412','Friday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190413','Saturday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190414','Sunday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190415','Monday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190416','Tuesday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190417','Wednesday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190418','Thursday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190419','Friday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190420','Saturday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190421','Sunday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190422','Monday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190423','Tuesday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190424','Wednesday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190425','Thursday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190426','Friday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190427','Saturday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190428','Sunday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190429','Monday')
    insert into @alldates values ('20190430','Tuesday')
```

Comment: use the same Logic I posted 10 dys ago with some slight changes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55764772/how-to-generate-list-of-weekday-dates-excluding-holidays-as-per-defined-rule

Comment: @Kemal AL GAZZAH your query was helpful but I want to create a logic without hard coding query condition so that if any new schedule will be added date would generate automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, using the same logic [the one of 19/04/2019 I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55764772/how-to-generate-list-of-weekday-dates-excluding-holidays-as-per-defined-rule),

Please insert into @tabholiday the holiday dates of your country

```
declare @tabholiday as table(holiday_date date)

declare @tab_monday as table (m int,date_found date)
declare @tab_monday2 as table (m int,date_found date)
declare @tab_tuesday as table (m int,date_found date)
declare @tab_wednesday as table (m int,date_found date)
declare @tab_friday as table (m int,date_found date)
declare @tab_saturday as table (m int,date_found date)
declare @tab_saturday2 as table (m int,date_found date)

insert into @tabholiday values('2019/01/07'),('2019/01/11'),('2019/03/20'),('2019/04/09'),('2019/05/01'),('2019/07/25'),('2019/08/13'),('2019/10/15')
declare @calendar as table(wd int,fulldate date,dayname varchar(20),m int,weekday_rank_month int,holiday int)

--Script by Kemal AL GAZZAH
--26/04/2019

set dateformat dmy

--Filling the @Calendar Table------------

;WITH cte as (SELECT cast('01/01/2019' as date) as d 
UNION ALL SELECT dateadd(day,1,d)  AS d FROM cte WHERE year(dateadd(day,1,d))=2019 ) 
insert into @calendar SELECT cast(replace(d,'-','') as int) wd,d fulldate,
case datepart(w,d)
when 1 then 'Sunday'
when 2 then 'Monday'
when 3 then 'Tuesday'
when 4 then 'Wednesday'
when 5 then 'Thursday'
when 6 then 'Friday'
when 7 then 'Saturday'
end

 [dayname] ,month(d) [M]
 ,row_number() over (partition by datepart(w,d),month(d) order by d) weekday_rank_month,case isnull(t2.holiday_date,'') when '' then 0 else 1 end [holiday]

 FROM cte t1 left outer join @tabholiday t2 on t1.d=t2.holiday_date

  order by d 
 OPTION (MAXRECURSION 366);




 --1 )Monday after third thursday of month 
  ;
  with cte as
  (
  select t1.m[Month],t2.fulldate d1,t2.holiday,t3.fulldate d2  from @calendar t1 
  outer apply(select top 1 * from  @calendar t2 where t2.dayname='monday' and t2.fulldate > t1.fulldate order by fulldate) t2
  outer apply (select top 1 * from @calendar t3 where fulldate > t2.fulldate and holiday=0 and month(fulldate)=t1.m order by fulldate ) t3
  where t1.weekday_rank_month=3 and t1.dayname='thursday')
  insert into @tab_monday 
  select 
  [Month],
  case 
  when holiday=0 then d1 
  else d2
  end [Monday after third thursday of month] from cte

 --2)wednesday before third thursday of month in active_in_months
  ;
  with cte as
  (
  select t1.m[Month],t2.fulldate d1,t2.holiday,t3.fulldate d2  from @calendar t1 
  outer apply(select top 1 * from  @calendar t2 where t2.dayname='wednesday' and t2.fulldate < t1.fulldate order by fulldate) t2
  outer apply (select top 1 * from @calendar t3 where fulldate > t2.fulldate and holiday=0 and month(fulldate)=t1.m order by fulldate ) t3
  where t1.weekday_rank_month=3 and t1.dayname='thursday')
  insert into @tab_wednesday 
  select 
  [Month],
  case 
  when holiday=0 then d1 
  else d2
  end [wednesday before third thursday of month in active_in_months] from cte

  --3)Tuesday after second thursday of month in active_in_months
  ;
  with cte as
  (
  select t1.m[Month],t2.fulldate d1,t2.holiday,t3.fulldate d2  from @calendar t1 
  outer apply(select top 1 * from  @calendar t2 where t2.dayname='Tuesday' and t2.fulldate > t1.fulldate order by fulldate) t2
  outer apply (select top 1 * from @calendar t3 where fulldate > t2.fulldate and holiday=0 and month(fulldate)=t1.m order by fulldate ) t3
  where t1.weekday_rank_month=2 and t1.dayname='thursday')
  insert into @tab_Tuesday 
  select 
  [Month],
  case 
  when holiday=0 then d1 
  else d2
  end [Tuesday after second thursday of month in active_in_months] from cte

 --4)monday after third friday of month in active_in_months
  ;
  with cte as
  (
  select t1.m[Month],t2.fulldate d1,t2.holiday,t3.fulldate d2  from @calendar t1 
  outer apply(select top 1 * from  @calendar t2 where t2.dayname='monday' and t2.fulldate > t1.fulldate order by fulldate) t2
  outer apply (select top 1 * from @calendar t3 where fulldate > t2.fulldate and holiday=0 and month(fulldate)=t1.m order by fulldate ) t3
  where t1.weekday_rank_month=3 and t1.dayname='friday')
  insert into @tab_Monday2 
  select 
  [Month],
  case 
  when holiday=0 then d1 
  else d2
  end [monday after third friday of month in active_in_months] from cte


 --5)Friday after second monday of month in active_in_months
  ;
  with cte as
  (
  select t1.m[Month],t2.fulldate d1,t2.holiday,t3.fulldate d2  from @calendar t1 
  outer apply(select top 1 * from  @calendar t2 where t2.dayname='Friday' and t2.fulldate > t1.fulldate order by fulldate) t2
  outer apply (select top 1 * from @calendar t3 where fulldate > t2.fulldate and holiday=0 and month(fulldate)=t1.m order by fulldate ) t3
  where t1.weekday_rank_month=2 and t1.dayname='monday')
  insert into @tab_Friday
  select 
  [Month],
  case 
  when holiday=0 then d1 
  else d2
  end [Friday after second monday of month in active_in_months] from cte


  --6)saturday after second friday of month in active_in_months
  ;
  with cte as
  (
  select t1.m[Month],t2.fulldate d1,t2.holiday,t3.fulldate d2  from @calendar t1 
  outer apply(select top 1 * from  @calendar t2 where t2.dayname='Saturday' and t2.fulldate > t1.fulldate order by fulldate) t2
  outer apply (select top 1 * from @calendar t3 where fulldate > t2.fulldate and holiday=0 and month(fulldate)=t1.m order by fulldate ) t3
  where t1.weekday_rank_month=2 and t1.dayname='Friday')
  insert into @tab_saturday
  select 
  [Month],
  case 
  when holiday=0 then d1 
  else d1 --d2 (no effect on holiday)
  end [saturday after second friday of month in active_in_months] from cte

  --7)saturday after second monday of month in active_in_months
  ;
  with cte as
  (
  select t1.m[Month],t2.fulldate d1,t2.holiday,t3.fulldate d2  from @calendar t1 
  outer apply(select top 1 * from  @calendar t2 where t2.dayname='Saturday' and t2.fulldate > t1.fulldate order by fulldate) t2
  outer apply (select top 1 * from @calendar t3 where fulldate > t2.fulldate and holiday=0 and month(fulldate)=t1.m order by fulldate ) t3
  where t1.weekday_rank_month=2 and t1.dayname='monday')
  insert into @tab_saturday2
  select 
  [Month],
  case 
  when holiday=0 then d1 
  else d1 --d2 (no effect on holiday)
  end [saturday after second friday of month in active_in_months] from cte


   --8)-Jointure Between 7 Tables





 select t1.m [Month],
 t1.date_found [Monday1],
 t2.date_found [Monday2],
 t3.date_found [Tuesday],
 t4.date_found [Wednesady],
 t5.date_found [Friday],
 t6.date_found [Saturday1],
 t7.date_found [Saturday2]

 from  @tab_monday t1 
 inner join @tab_monday2 t2 on t1.m=t2.m
 inner join @tab_tuesday t3 on t1.m=t3.m
 inner join @tab_wednesday t4 on t1.m=t4.m
 inner join @tab_friday t5 on t1.m=t5.m
 inner join @tab_saturday t6 on t1.m=t6.m
 inner join @tab_saturday2 t7 on t1.m=t7.m
```